# AWS Application Load Balancer rejecting requests with content-length 0

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-application-load-balancer, rfc

I'm having some issues sending a GET request to a service that contains no body and in the headers Content-Length:0 (ALB returns 400 bad request). By looking at [AWS documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/load-balancer-access-logs.html) they state that is classified as Acceptable [image]

where the definition of Acceptable is found [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/application-load-balancers.html#desync-mitigation-mode):

- Acceptable — Request does not comply with RFC 7230 but poses no known security threats.

I browsed a bit through the RFC and and the only thing I found is this statement:

- A user agent **SHOULD NOT** send a
  Content-Length header field when the request message does not contain
  a payload body **AND** the method semantics do not anticipate such a
  body.

I bolded out the key words that make a GET request with no body and with Content-Length:0 compliant with RFC 7230.

Do you understand why AWS says it's not compliant ?

**EDIT:**
ALB is configured in Strictest mode for the desync mitigation mode configuration and treats Acceptable requests as blocked
[image]

Comment: How do you know that it's the ALB that's returning the 400 and not your backend service?

Comment: Monitoring logs and checking that the request doesn't reach my service

Comment: You should edit your question to show those logs. FWIW, I just tried `curl -v -H 'Content-Length: 0' REDACTED` against an ALB-fronted server I control, and it returned the expected response (not 400).

Comment: I think I forgot to mention that the ALB is configured in Strictest mode for the desync mitigation mode. Will update the description.

Comment: So, let's see if I understand what you're telling us: you've configured your load balancer to block requests that are classified as "Acceptable", and you're wondering why it's returning a 400 and not sending the request to the back-end?

Comment: Almost. I am wondering why this request is tagged as Acceptable(see AWS definition in my question) when the RFC says it's a compliant request? Also other load balancer like haproxy see this request as a valid one